# Rails 3 merging scopes with joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

## Setup

For this question, I'll use the following three classes:

```
class SolarSystem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :planets

  scope :has_earthlike_planet, joins(:planets).merge(Planet.like_earth)
end

class Planet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :solar_system
  belongs_to :planet_type

  scope :like_earth, joins(:planet_type).where(:planet_types => {:life => true, :gravity => 9.8})
end

class PlanetType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :planets

  attr_accessible :gravity, :life
end
```

## Problem

The scope `has_earthlike_planet` does not work. It gives me the following error:

> ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'planet_type' was
>   not found; perhaps you misspelled it?

## Question

I have found out that this is because it is equivalent to the following:

```
joins(:planets, :planet_type)...
```

and SolarSystem does not have a `planet_type` association. I'd like to use the `like_earth` scope on `Planet`, the `has_earthlike_planet` on `SolarSystem`, and would like to avoid duplicating code and conditions. Is there a way to merge these scopes like I'm attempting to do but am missing a piece? If not, what other techniques can I use to accomplish these goals?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently, at this time you can only merge simple constructs that don't involve joins.  Here is a possible workaround if you modify your models to look like this:

```
class SolarSystem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :planets
  has_many :planet_types, :through => :planets

  scope :has_earthlike_planet, joins(:planet_types).merge(PlanetType.like_earth)
end

class Planet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :solar_system
  belongs_to :planet_type

  scope :like_earth, joins(:planet_type).merge(PlanetType.like_earth)
end

class PlanetType < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :planets

   attr_accessible :gravity, :life

   scope :like_earth, where(:life => true, :gravity => 9.8)
end
```

** UPDATE **

For the record, a [bug was filed](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5494) about this behavior - hopefully will be fixed soon...

Comment: I like the idea of moving the conditions to the model that they work on to keep the logic there and simply make simpler merges up the chain. The only issue with this simple example is that given the available structure and information, it is incredibly unlikely that there will be more than one PlanetType record that is `like_earth`. This makes the base scope seem out of place, however, it might be the best place for it until that bug is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You are reusing the conditions from the scope `Planet.like_earth`, which joins `planet_type`. When these conditions are merged, the `planet_type` association is being called on `SolarSystem`, which doesn't exist.

A `SolarSystem` has many `planet_types` through `planets`, but this is still not the right association name, since it is pluralized. You can add the following to the `SolarSystem` class to setup the `planet_type` association, which is just an alias for `planet_types`. You can't use the Ruby `alias` however since AREL reflects on the association macros, and doesn't query on whether the model responds to a method by that name:

```
class SolarSystem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :planets
  has_many :planet_types, :through => :planets
  has_many :planet_type, :through => :planets, :class_name => 'PlanetType'

  scope :has_earthlike_planet, joins(:planets).merge(Planet.like_earth)
end

SolarSystem.has_earthlike_planet.to_sql # => SELECT "solar_systems".* FROM "solar_systems" INNER JOIN "planets" ON "planets"."solar_system_id" = "solar_systems"."id" INNER JOIN "planets" "planet_types_solar_systems_join" ON "solar_systems"."id" = "planet_types_solar_systems_join"."solar_system_id" INNER JOIN "planet_types" ON "planet_types"."id" = "planet_types_solar_systems_join"."planet_type_id" WHERE "planet_types"."life" = 't' AND "planet_types"."gravity" = 9.8
```

Comment: Fortunately, there is no such thing as the "Enterprise" for the citizens of Tattoine. I think you mean the Empire. Second, there is no spice on Tattoine - its all on Kessel. Finally, I think you meant "planet", not "plant". :P

Comment: It seems like this creates an extra temporary relationship called `planet_types_solar_systems_join`. If I change the scope to `scope :has_earthlike_planet, joins(:planet_type).merge(Planet.like_earth)` (note the joining on `planet_type` instead of `planets`) the query looks correct. I know that behind the scenes it is doing `SolarSystem.joins(:planet_type, :planet_type)` but since it doesn't have any side effect, I think I'm okay with it. It definitely feels like a hack though to get around Rails not maintaining where the joins go by using modified associations.

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution that I found is that you can change your joins in your Planet class to

```
joins(Planet.joins(:planet_type).join_sql)
```

This will create an SQL string for the joins which will always include the correct table names and therefore should always be working no matter if you call the scope directly or use it in a merge. It's not that nice looking and may be a bit of a hack, but it's only a little more code and there's no need to change your associations.